# Why does replaceWith() not trigger the same way as css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, replacewith

I'm trying to trigger a change in the content of a fixed div when you scroll past the top of an image.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;

    var img_position = $('img').position();

    if(y_scroll_pos > img_position.top) {
        $(".fixed").replaceWith(
            "<p>Goodbye!</p>"
        );
    }

    else {
        $(".fixed").replaceWith(
            "<p>Hello!</p>"
        );
    }

[...]
```

This only works if your window is scrolled to that point or below on load, even though window.pageYOffset is, obviously, continuously changing as you scroll.

But this example, with css(), changes as it should.

```
if(y_scroll_pos > img_position.top) {
        $(".fixed").css(
            "background-color","red";
        );
    }

    else {
        $(".fixed").css(
            "background-color","yellow";
        );
    }

[...]
```

Why? What's the difference between these two methods?

Comment: have you seen what the official jQuery documentation says about the `.replaceWith()` method?

Comment: Haha, oh man. Yeah I did indeed, quite a few times in fact, just somehow completely failed to process what was happening + assumed that .replaceWith() replaced the content of the element rather than the element itself. My bad.

Comment: Exactly, unlike `.html()` - replaceWith does exactly that: "instead of ME - put THAT" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why changing completely the HTML when you can change only the desired content?

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // (DOM is now ready)

    var $img = $('img');                 // Cache your elements outside of expensive
    var $fixedP = $('.fixed').find("p"); // scroll events

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pastTop = window.pageYOffset > $img.position(); // Boolean value        
        $fixedP.text(pastTop ? "Goodbye!" : "Hello!" )
               .css({background: pastTop ? "red" : "yellow"});
    }

});
```